# How does match multiple IP Address after comma?

Tags: python, regex, ip-address

A IP list for example:

```
5.2.69.50
5.104.110.89,5.183.209.217 
5.199.143.202,18.27.197.252,23.31.59.211,23.114.165.250
23.129.64.137
23.129.64.148,23.129.64.150,23.129.64.157,23.129.64.163
```

I this case using `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` I wil match all these ips, but in this cases, I'd like the IP which repeat it self.

Ouput Desired

```
(5.104.110.89,5.183.209.217) 
(5.199.143.202,18.27.197.252,23.31.59.211,23.114.165.250)
(23.129.64.148,23.129.64.150,23.129.64.157,23.129.64.163)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'd like the IP which repeat it self"? Are you looking for *lines* with at least two IPs? Why not just look for ``,`` instead?

Comment: Note that ``\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`` is not sufficient to accurately match only valid IPs. It will match nonsense "IPs" such as 999.999.999.999, and is obviously not suitable for IPv6.

Comment: Do not matter if it is not sufficient to match only valid IPs. Answering your first question, because reading the lines I always will have one IP, but if two appears, it need to be filter.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include the comma `,` token and only match lines that have at least two matches?

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(,|$)){2,}
```

[<sup>regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/4GqMyi/1)

Comment: for @ThiagoL information, this pattern does not recognize valid IPs.

Comment: @Alireza These addresses being "valid" according to the standard IP address specification that doesn't seem to be in the OP's original requirement. If it is part of their requirements, I would encourage them to update their question to reflect as such.

Comment: Yes, I just said for OP information.

Comment: Why does it not match with second line? `5.104.110.89,5.183.209.217`

Comment: @ThiagoL Typo on my part - the `m` flag shouldn’t have been enabled - see [updated regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4GqMyi/1)